# Code Push functionality not working for react native app

Tags: android, react-native, code-push

I am new to code push and react native, I followed the steps given in the official docs- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/react-native#getting-started, but even after pushing code to appcenter, it is not updating the app. Please find below the necessary code.

Index.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import codePush from 'react-native-code-push';
let codePushOptions = {checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_START};
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => codePush(codePushOptions)(App));
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.awesomeproject;

import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
          return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.awesomeproject.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

strings.xml

```
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">AwesomeProject</string>
    <string moduleConfig="true" name="CodePushDeploymentKey">"I have added the deployment key here"</string>
</resources>
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.9",
    "appcenter-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.2.4",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.2.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Appcenter Code-push screenshot
[Appcenter code push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PONTQ.png)

Please let me know, if there's anything else need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, I had React native version 0.62 and code Push only supported react native version 0.61 and below at the time I made this post. So I just downgraded the version to 0.61 and now codePush is working fine.